# Traefik static configuration problem with environment variables

Tags: traefik

Is it possible to use environment variables to configure the traefik statik configuration?
I using a simple as possible traefik compose file and a sample pgsql container.

Here it is:

the traefik:

```
version: '3'

services:

  traefik:

    image: traefik:v3.0
    environment:
      - TRAEFIK_API_INSECURE=true
      - TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_DOCKER=true
      - TRAEFIK_LOG_LEVEL=INFO
      - TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_WEBSECURE=true
      - TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_WEB=true
      - TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_WEB_ADDRESS=:80
      - TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_WEBSECURE_ADDRESS=:443
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

and the pgsql:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}
    restart: always
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.ec-pgsql.rule=Host(`test-pgsql.test.hu`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.ec-pgsql.entrypoints=http"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${PG_USER:?"Set Postgersql usename in ./.env or or give the parameter in jenkins"}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${PG_PASSWORD:?"Set Postgersql password in ./.env or give the paremeter in jenkins"}
      - LC_ALL=$LC_ALL
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ${PGSQL_DATA:?"Set PGSQL_DATA environment"}:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

and the traefik error is:

```
2024-02-27T13:04:30Z INF Starting provider *docker.Provider
2024-02-27T13:04:31Z ERR EntryPoint doesn't exist entryPointName=http routerName=ec-pgsql@docker
2024-02-27T13:04:31Z ERR No valid entryPoint for this router routerName=test-pgsql@docker
```

if i remove this:

```
- TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_WEBSECURE=true
- TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_WEB=true
- TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_WEB_ADDRESS=:80
- TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_WEBSECURE_ADDRESS=:443
```

from the traefik is just working fine so it's clear I use this variables wrong.

I want multiple traefik instances to configure the static configuration from jenkins so if I need to change anything in a static conf I just do it in the jenkins and then reboot.

I resolved it is the order of the env.

```
- TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_WEB=true
- TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_WEBSECURE=true
- TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_WEB_ADDRESS=:80
- TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_WEBSECURE_ADDRESS=:443
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

Your entrypoint configuration does not match the labels you give to the service. Looking at the [Traefik Documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/reference/static-configuration/env/), the entrypoint variable is of form `TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_<NAME>`.

So, if you have a variable `- TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_WEB=true`, what is the entrypoint name? `WEB` of course.

However, in your `db` service you have this label:

```
      - "traefik.http.routers.ec-pgsql.entrypoints=http"
```

And the error you get is `2024-02-27T13:04:31Z ERR EntryPoint doesn't exist entryPointName=http routerName=ec-pgsql@docker`

So in other words, you are trying to use entrypoint `http`, which does not exist.

### Solution

Change the label to:

```
      - "traefik.http.routers.ec-pgsql.entrypoints=WEB"
```

and it should work.